# Iterating over Dataframes to generate new Dataframes in Python with Power BI

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Using python in power BI to process data prior to entering the visuals in report.

Example of what I'm doing:

Purchase order database comes from oracle.
Supply database comes from multiple loc (SQL/csv).

Purchase order X requires 20 units of a / 30 units of b  (e.g)

I have made it work with the below code - but I have yet to run it across a full sized dataset - all the threads i've accessed basically say the way I'm doing it is not ideal - I was curious if there is a simpler more memory efficient way of accomplishing this.

I/o sources are pandas dataframes in PBI - it also supports numpy and a couple others as far as I'm aware.

Code below shows how i'm doing it presently - it works very quickly on sample size of 500 or so rows - want to make sure I can scale it up though.

The below example is using 2 dataframes: (df1 is the demand table and df2 is the supply table) to allocate the supply material over the orders) df3 is the temp array for storing the calculation.

To further clarify - main concern is the iterrows() and that concern is purely based on what I've read (mostly on this site)

Edit:  Thank you so much for taking time to read and help me!
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239974/eva-vw

Not sure how to add the output but here is what the data looks like (in pictures)[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYTGX.png)

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV5J2.png)

I didn't think I could merge them since the alloy tag in df1 is a requirement value and the alloy tag in df2 is an inventory value - that would be awesome if I could - I will give your code a try and let you know!  Thank you again.

Oh one last detail - the "Counter" column I made was just to keep the index at where the requirement is - when I did the same code without it my df3 that I eventually combine to make my final df4 was only as many rows long as orders I allocated for - I wanted it to stay aligned with df1 so I could put them together at the end - when I added a value in there for each iteration it kept the proper location.  Df3 ends up like Counter:, Allocated  and then that gets added to DF1 so that Lbs(Required) and Allocated are together with the orders.

Edit:  Final output after switching to merge of df1: [df1 with merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k1Gh.png)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239974/eva-vw

Edit:  Final output with original code iterrows(): df4: [df4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Jqu.png)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239974/eva-vw

Edit: Final output with adjusted function: [image: df1adjusted]
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239974/eva-vw

To explain more - there was 53000 lbs of this component in inventory - so it stops allocating once it exhausts the inventory with the iterrows - but i think I can figure this portion out now that I understand your logic.

Also btw - your code executed instantly - where as the iterrows loads for about a second - so from scaling perspective I'm very excited about this!

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name': ['a','b','c'], 'Alloy': ['R80','R80','R80'], 'Lbs': [6400,6400,6400]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ITEM': ['R80'], 'Inv': [50000]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3["Allocated"] = ""
df3["Counter"] = ""
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    x = df2.at[i, 'ITEM']
    y = df2.at[i, 'Inv']
    g = 0
    for j, row in df1.iterrows():
        g+=1
        df3.at[j, 'Counter'] = g
        if df1.at[j, 'Alloy'] == x:
            z = df1.at[j, 'Lbs']
            if y >= z:
                df3.at[j, 'Allocated'] = z
                y = y - z
            else:
                break

df4 = pd.concat([df1,df3],axis=1)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide input data, expected outputs, and explanation of logic.

Comment: Example for input data:  df1:  Item: A, qty(lbs): 5,000   - list of items and on hand inventory.  df2: PO #:, A required:, B required:, C required:  expected is output is to use up all of the inventory of each item on orders until it's gone - so distributing the inventory across the orders - which will then be added to the master order array (df1)

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to get a sample of your input data (just df.head() would work) and a more detailed explanation of the calculation using your column names.

Does this replicate your logic? This cuts out one of your loops. If you confirm that this is what you want to do, we can think more about how to speed it up.

```py
# merge ITEM and Inv info from df2 into df1 based on overlap between Alloy and ITEM
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['ITEM', 'Inv']], how='left', left_on=['Alloy'], right_on=['ITEM'])
# set base allocation to Inv
df1['Allocated'] = df1['Inv']

def subtract_lbs(row):
    item = row['ITEM']
    allocated = row['Allocated']
    lbs = row['Lbs']
    if allocated >= lbs:
        remaining = allocated-lbs
        df1.loc[df1['ITEM'] == item, 'Allocated'] = remaining
        return remaining
    else:
        return allocated

# iteratively subtract lbs from allocated
df1['Allocated'] = df1.apply(subtract_lbs, axis=1)
```

EDIT: Above method does updated df1['Allocated'] properly because df1.loc does not produce expected behavior while df1.apply is executing. Using a temporary df.

```py
# merge ITEM and Inv info from df2 into df1 based on overlap between Alloy and ITEM
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['ITEM', 'Inv']], how='left', left_on=['Alloy'], right_on=['ITEM'])
# create temporary dataframe for the calculation
temp_df = df1.copy()
# set base allocation to Inv
temp_df['Allocated'] = temp_df['Inv']

def subtract_lbs(row):
    item = row['ITEM']
    lbs = row['Lbs']
    allocated = temp_df.loc[temp_df['ITEM'] == item, 'Allocated'].values[0]
    if allocated >= lbs:
        remaining = allocated-lbs
        temp_df.loc[df1['ITEM'] == item, 'Allocated'] = remaining
        return remaining
    else:
        return allocated

# iteratively subtract lbs from allocated
df1['Allocated'] = df1.apply(subtract_lbs, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello! I added an edit in the OP with pictures of df1 / df2 top 5 rows.  Df3 is just an empty df I make for storing the values that I've allocated for each requirement.  What I'm doing is starting out with my first ITEM (in this case alloy) and then looping through the requirements and allocating it - if I have more or = the requirement - i add it - until I don't then I break to the next alloy.  Alloy and ITEM do overlap - so I think this should work!  I'm going to try it out and post back - thanks again so much for taking the time.

Comment: Hey so an update on here - forgive me I'm not that familiar with merge but I got a syntax error: I added it as a link in the OP - it points at where how = 'left' after df1,

Comment: Yep was a typo. merge(df1) should have been merge(df2[['ITEM', 'Inv']]. Made an edit.

Comment: Would be great if you could add some code to your question to create sample input data. You can do something like df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1': [0,1,2], 'col2':  [3,4,5]})

Comment: Updated! Hope that helps - kept the names the same so it would be easier - Also - reran with the updated code you provided - the merge worked - the inv column stays constant and the allocated column decreases by the lbs quantity!  So in the end the Inv column would want to decrease by the lbs per order and the allocated column would want to match the lbs per order - I'm thinking I can accomplish both of these things! this is so great and helped me learn a ton!  I'm going to read up more on how the merge works.  Thank you again so much.

Comment: Also going to post what the output looked like in the OP so you can see - I can probably adjust the function to make it so that Inventory goes down as it is allocated and the allocated quantity will just equal the lbs quantity until the inventory is too low to satisfy which will prompt the material requisition

Comment: Absolutely all done.  I wanted to leave PBI in the title only because it only lets you work with certain packages as far as I'm aware so I thought that would limit the responses to ones that would work in PBI (since this is the application I'm using in this case).

Comment: Ah with your test data I can see that 'Allocated' is not getting updated properly. Might still need to use iterrows for that section, trying some alternatives now...

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment asking you to tag, my bad.

Comment: Yeah I think it's just based on how the function is written - I was thinking to just subtract lbs from inventory into a "net inventory" column and then add lbs to an allocated column as long as net inventory >= lbs - i think this will work.  Not sure though since in my brain that requires maintaining the net inventory value through iteration -

Comment: Got it to work in a kind of hacky way using a temporary df. The issue was that I was trying to update values in df1 using df1.loc while df1.apply was executing. Because of the way apply works, df1.loc was not actually updating iteratively. Works when you pass the value back to a temporary df.

Comment: Awesome! I will try it out and let you know how it goes

Comment: So I added another edit to show what it does - it's improved from previous cause you can see it subtracting down the lbs for each order but it's returning the total lbs left vs. the total lbs allocated (which should just be equal to the Lbs column)  I tried thinking of a way to add another column to generate that after it's done but I'm a bit stumped -

Comment: Ok definitely have some kind of misunderstanding about what you're looking for. Could you add an example of your ideal output?

Comment: Hey so it's in the OP - it's the picture of what happens with the iterrows(): df4 - basically to match the lbs value of the purchase orders with the inventory value until all of the inventory is gone - then to put 0's for allocated after that so it will automatically prompt purchase orders for more material to cover those orders etc.